# restrict the user to copy and paste characters in the text box which is declared as Numeric text box by using key press event injquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to restrict the user to copy and paste characters in the text box which is declared as Numeric text box by using key press event in jquery

Answer (score 0):

try below

**html**

```
<input type="text" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" >
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#TextBox1").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#TextBox1').bind('copy paste cut',function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste

 });
});
```

this will disable copy, paste functionalists, it will only allow user to enter numbers
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h9xq49kz/1/)**